# Making a UIButton stay put on top of table view rss feed cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, rss, tableview

I have an rss app and the in the table view controller I have a UIButton on top of the feed with an image that when clicked, brings up the full website in safari. The button cell scrolls with the rest of the feed and doesn't stay put on top when scrolling through the feed. How can I make it so that the uibutton placed in the table view stays on top and just the articles are scroll-able? I also am placing a uibutton with another link on the bottom.

This is the IBAction i created for to the button in the table view that works:

```
-(IBAction) linkButton {
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@" placed my url here"]]; 

}
```

Do I put any code inside the IBAction to make it stay put? Or is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Don't add the button to the table view. Put the button in the nav bar or tool bar.

Answer (score -2):

u can make custom Headerview with a UIButton

Comment: How do I do that? I already have the uibutton placed where I want it to be in the table view controller